# Building Tesseract with Android NDK

Tags: android-ndk, tesseract

I'm following [this](http://kurup87.blogspot.ca/2012/03/android-ocr-tutorial-image-to-text.html) tutorial to compile [this](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two) fork of Tesseract (an optical character recognition package) for Android.   I'm at the step where I use Cygwin to build the NDK for the Tesseract Android project.  I'm getting the following error when invoking ndk-build (from the tess-two directory):

```
c:/android-ndk-r8b-windows/android-ndk-r8b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6.x-google/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: cannot find ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_static.a: Permission denied
```

What could be causing this error?  On a side note, is there an easier way to get Tesseract up and running on Android?

Comment: Why not installing Ubuntu? It is a 2 hour work today. Cygwin is broken...

Comment: I've been a bit reluctant to use a VM.  Once I've installed the NDK and built Tesseract using it, can I then work with the project on Windows?

Comment: It is probably possible with a few hacks and binary copies but definitely not recommended. Mainly because you will end up in a near future where you'll have to hack and rebuild the native part... I strongly recommend you to install native Linux distro (Ubuntu if you are a beginner), either with a dual-boot (grub2) or a VM. Personally I avoid VM because they do dark magic with device drivers. For instance, usb rarely works out of the box on a VM... Now, my comment does not answer your original question, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under Windows, run your command prompt as an administrator and try again:

Search->cmd.exe->Right-click->Run as Administrator

Cygwin is unnecessary--just use Windows itself. You can follow the [README](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two) build instructions on the Tesseract fork. The blog you're following makes the process more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Good tip!  Unfortunately, I'm getting the same error in Windows.  I've tried running both Cygwin and cmd.exe as administrator, as well as setting permissions on the parent folder of the NDK to full control.  By the way, in case anyone is confused about how to run this on Windows (I was) if the NDK is not in your PATH, the best way is to type `C:\android-ndk-r8b-windows\android-ndk-r8b\ndk-build`.  A bit different than in Linux.

Comment: Okay, nevermind, if I use `ndk-build j8` it builds on Windows!   `android update project --path` tells me there are subprojects I can update, but I only see one project inside tess-two. `ant release` appears to work fine.  I load tess-two into my Eclipse workspace and link it as a library to my app.  I end up with the error `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load lept: findLibrary returned null` when I try running my app.

Comment: The full command is `android update project --path .` -- don't forget the ending `.` to indicate the current directory.

Comment: Ah thanks, I actually did `android update project --path ../tess-two` as a work-around but your way is cleaner.  In any case, that's not the cause of the problem :(

Comment: For newbies like me in NDK the correct command our buddy has mentioned is ndk-build -j8 and even then if you get the error /obj/local/armeabi/libgnustl_static.a: Permission denied then use chmod 777 obj/local/armeabi/libgnustl_static.a and ndk-build again

Answer (score 0):

First check whether you are able to compile samples in the ndk.
And 'make' sure cygwin is installed.. Compilation problem occurs from installation or packages not yet installed. Early I worked with tesseract and have not found any problem.

Thus Tesseract OCR is used to refer a library to your project.. As example, check [this](https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr) . Use test-two and it worked.

Comment: I tried building the NDK for your example project and got the following error: `Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: ./jni/Android.mk`.  I have `gcc-core, gcc-g++, make, swig` installed as the tutorial suggests.  I've tried running as administrator and using the command-line argument -j8 (which at least compiled a fair bit more stuff before getting stuck at the same error).

Comment: yeah.. I got similar to your issue but solved by changing the path from c:/android-ndk-r8b-windows/android-ndk-r8b/ to c:/android-ndk-r8b/ also set your mycomp->properties->environmental build path as per ndk.

Comment: What do you mean by changing the path?  Currently, I invoke ndk-build directly from the project folder (../../../../../cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r8b-windows/android-ndk-r8b/ or some such ugly thing).