# UnsatisfiedLinkError - Tesseract for Android

Tags: android, ant, android-ndk, tesseract, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I downloaded Tesseract OCR for Android from [here](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two) and I'm trying to build it as a library project for my own app using the NDK.  I've received some useful feedback on how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469711/building-tesseract-with-android-ndk/12541069#comment16898006_12541069).  First, I do this on the command-line ([path] is shorthand for the path to the tess-two project):

```
> cd [path]\tess-two

> C:\android-ndk-r8b-windows\android-ndk-r8b\ndk-build -j8

"Compile thumb : lept <= adaptmap.c

[...]

"Compile++ thumb : lept <= writefile.cpp

Prebuilt       : libgnustl_static.a <= <NDK>/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/

"Compile++ thumb : tess <= applybox.cpp

[...]

"Compile++ thumb : tess <= tessbaseapi.cpp

"Compile thumb : lept <= adaptmap.c

[...]

"Compile++ thumb : lept <= pixa.cpp

Prebuilt       : libgnustl_static.a <= <NDK>/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi-v7a/

"Compile++ thumb : lept <= jni.cpp

[...]

"Compile++ thumb : tess <= tessbaseapi.cpp

"Compile x86  : lept <= affine.c

[...]

"Compile++ x86  : lept <= readfile.cpp

Prebuilt       : libgnustl_static.a <= <NDK>/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/x86/

"Compile++ x86  : tess <= baseapi.cpp

[...]

"Compile++ x86  : tess <= wordclass.cpp

SharedLibrary  : liblept.so

SharedLibrary  : liblept.so

"Compile++ x86  : tess <= tessbaseapi.cpp

SharedLibrary  : liblept.so

"Compile++ x86  : tess <= wordrec.cpp

SharedLibrary  : libtess.so

Install        : liblept.so => libs/x86/liblept.so

Install        : liblept.so => libs/armeabi/liblept.so

SharedLibrary  : libtess.so

Install        : liblept.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/liblept.so

SharedLibrary  : libtess.so

Install        : libtess.so => libs/armeabi/libtess.so

Install        : libtess.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libtess.so

Install        : libtess.so => libs/x86/libtess.so


> C:\Users\User\android-sdk\tools\android.bat update project --path .

Failed to convert path to a short DOS path: C:\Windows\system32\java.exe
'javaw_exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Updated local.properties

Updated file [path]\tess-two\proguard-project.txt

It seems that there are sub-projects. If you want to update them

please use the --subprojects parameter.

> set JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\JDK
> Buildfile: [path]\tess-two\build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-release-mode:

-release-obfuscation-check:
     [echo] proguard.config is ${proguard.config}

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 20.0.3
 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Users\User\android-sdks

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: tess-two
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

-build-setup:
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for tess-two...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Google APIs
[gettarget] Vendor:           Google Inc.
[gettarget] Platform Version: 4.1
[gettarget] API level:        16
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for tess-two...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'release'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

-pre-build:

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
[renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found new input file
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
     [echo] Creating library output jar file...

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
     [echo] Library project: do not convert bytecode...

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: [path]\tess-two\res
   [crunch] To destination dir: [path]\tess-two\bin\res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [echo] Library project: do not package resources...

-package:
     [echo] Library project: do not package apk...

-post-package:

-release-prompt-for-password:

-release-nosign:
     [echo] 
[propertyfile] Updating property file: [path]\tess-two\bin\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: [path]\tess-two\bin\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: [path]\tess-two\bin\build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: [path]\tess-two\bin\build.prop

-release-sign:

-post-build:

release:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

Then, I do this:
File -> Import -> Android -> Existing Code Into Workspace -> Browse -> Select current workspace directory -> Make sure tess-two is selected in the list that comes up -> Finish.

Then I right-click on my own app, go to Properties -> Android tab -> Add... (under Library section) -> select tess-two -> Click OK -> Check "Is Library" -> OK.

However, after all this, I *still* get the follwing error when running my app:

```
09-23 13:02:42.532: E/AndroidRuntime(675): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load lept: findLibrary returned null
09-23 13:02:42.532: E/AndroidRuntime(675):  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
09-23 13:02:42.532: E/AndroidRuntime(675):  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
09-23 13:02:42.532: E/AndroidRuntime(675):  at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(TessBaseAPI.java:47)
```

The project.properties for my own app is:

```
target=android-16
android.library.reference.1=..\\OpenCV\\sdk\\java
android.library.reference.2=../Tesseract/tess-two
android.library=true
```

What's going on?

Comment: If anyone can give me some feedback about what other information I should include to help others answer the question, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Include your project.properties too.

Comment: Don't check "is Library" for your own project. Tess-two should be the library project.

Comment: is Library is checked for tess-two.  Which project properties should I post (or both) and which project should I clean?

Comment: Post the `project.properties` for your app. Clean both.

Comment: Actually, you were totally right - I had checked is Library for my own project.  It wasn't working even before I did that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it, the problem was that I wasn't properly initializing the API in my code.  The proper syntax is:

```
tesseract.init("/mnt/sdcard/", "eng");
```

assuming you've got a folder "tessdata" under mnt/sdcard.  Now it loads perfectly!  Thanks so much for all your help, rmthesis!

Comment: hi plz help me where I have to write this line can u plz mention in which class

Answer (score 0):

for me instead of 2 loadlibrary I did all 4 as

`System.loadLibrary("jpgt");
    System.loadLibrary("pngt");
    System.loadLibrary("lept");
    System.loadLibrary("tess");`

and it worked.